# { of a stylesheet is unexpected when calling in Node.Js

Tags: node.js

In my `index.js` I am referencing my stylesheet via the below

```
var Code = require('./stylesheet.css');
```

However, when running my node app, I get the following error

```
button {
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
```

Pointing to my stylesheet with the below

```
button {
    background-color: #444444; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  .second_button {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
  };

   .third_button {
    background-color: #792895; 
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
  };
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you plan on doing with that variable?

Comment: @Mureinik I just need to reference it so that an API can call it

Comment: You have a syntax error…why not run it through a linter?

Comment: @EvanOttinger linter does not throw an error

Comment: You cant require a css file into node.js. What would you do with css in a js runtime? If you want to get the content of the css file, use the build in `fs` module. That what you try makes absolutely no sense.